# Set StackyClient Timeout

Tags: c#, timeout, httpwebrequest, stacky

I use the [StackyClient](http://stacky.codeplex.com/) library to loop over newest questions in Stack Overflow. Generally this works:

```
StackyClient client = new StackyClient("1.1", "", Sites.MetaStackOverflow, new UrlClient(), new JsonProtocol());
var o = new QuestionOptions();
...
IPagedList<Question> l = null;
while (!stop) {   
   l = client.GetQuestions(o);
   var newQuestions = (from Question q in l                      
                       orderby q.Id descending
                       select q).ToList();
   ...
}
```

But at some point this seems to fail. Maybe due to network connectivity problems or I don't know what. The program hangs at `client.GetQuestions(o)`.

I would like to detect that problem and reconnect again. **I thought about setting a timeout somehow to prevent the program from hanging. How can it be done?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible answers here:

1. Are you sure this is hanging?  Did you run it under a debugger and make sure it's not throwing an uncaught exception?  Did you check with ProcessExplorer and/or Fiddler to see that the request and socket are still open?  It seems more likely to me that the socket is being closed or you're getting an exception and it's not being caught.
2. If it is confirmed that this is hanging at GetQuestions, then a review of the code indicates that you'll have to ask the author of Stacky to implement this feature or you're going to have to implement it yourself... the feature does not exist today, from what I can tell.

In Stacky's UrlClient.cs there is a blocking call to HttpWebRequest.GetResponse and there is a blocking call to ReadToEnd on the response stream.  No timeout is being set for either call, nor on the HttpWebRequest object itself:

[Stacky/UrlClient.cs](https://bitbucket.org/lfoust/stacky/src/6b3df6a165375004431684aa8c4d7084426b5789/trunk/source/Stacky/UrlClient.cs?at=default)

In addition, I don't see anything in the connectionManagement settings that would allow setting a timeout on responses and reading from the response stream of HttpWebRequest:

[connectionManagement setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1tkaca2y.aspx)

The Stack UrlClient code is re-throwing WebExceptions other than 404 and 407 (proxy auth required), so if you got a 408 (the server timing you out) from StackOverflow it would throw out of the Stacky GetQuestions call, which is why I suspect it might be that you're seeing an uncaught exception and not a hang.

I periodically see 408's from StackOverflow when just browsing questions in Chrome, so it is possible that this is happening to your program and you just need to catch the exception and retry after a delay.

Hope this helps - Harold

Comment: You were right. I did not catch the exception correctly. Doing it now and it works.